# In IE Javascript execution speed is slower than Firefox, Safari and Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, optimization

In IE Java-script load slower than Firefox, Safari and Chrome?

Is there a way to load JavaScript quickly in IE also?

General best practice is to keep JavaScript at bottom of the page, does it make Js rendering more slow in IE?

**Edit:**

When we apply any jquery plugin to website to make any usable or interactivity then in IE effect shows slower than Other browsers.

We can easily identify the effect of condition on the page, before and after loading JS, which looks odd.

Comment: "General best practice is to keep JavaScript at bottom of the page" - if you use a document.ready / window.load that's a non-issue. How do you ask such poor questions and get so much rep.

Comment: Are you talking about the execution of the code or downloading? dom lockup? please be more specific than 'javascript load slower'

Comment: @Graphain it IS a good practice and while doesn't help much to get faster js execution time it affects overall page-load time in a very good way...

Comment: I request to SO admin to remove all my rep. I don't need them. I just ask any questions which comes in my mind. And i rely on SO users for better and quicker answer then Google.

If anyone has problem with my questions and then please tell to SO Admin to not give me any rep for any question

Comment: @galambalaz - how can it affect overall page-load time? The page is the same size to download and you've said it doesn't affect JS speed.

Comment: @Graphain scripts block other components. If they are at the bottom, however, they have nothing else to block, so the page loads more fluidly: http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The IE8 or below JavaScript engine sucks, it's *better* in IE8, but comparatively, it's still way behind...there's not a ton you can do about this if you're doing any heavy operations.

JavaScript is loaded and parsed each page, so the slower the engine, the slower the load...and that's the case with IE.  Keeping JavaScript at the bottom of the `<body>` is one option, to [prevent blocking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108225/non-blocking-javascript), but likely your issue is not the loading (as this would be from cache, if [your headers are set correctly](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/caching.html)), but the *execution*.

If it's any consolation, it seems IE9 is a major step forward, over IE8 at least.

It's a bit more general, but if you're looking to speed up your pages there are a few things to consider, [Google has a good list for this](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/rules_intro.html) and [Yahoo does too](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html).

Comment: Is removing all white space from JavaScript can help in loading speed in IE?

Comment: @metal-gear-solid - Absolutely. Run YUI Compressor on them: http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/

Comment: @metal-gear-solid - Yes, but *marginally* in most cases (I'm talking about **white space** in particular here).  [Since the content should be delivered via gzip](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/payload.html#GzipCompression) white space in particular will not have much of an impact, though minification renaming variables and such will.

Answer (score 1):

Not IE specific, but [BetterExplained](http://betterexplained.com/articles/speed-up-your-javascript-load-time/) has some good points on how to increase load times or in some cases, Web page response times.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of today's browsers, IE8's JS engine is slow, but [IE9's will perform much better](http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/benchmarks/SunSpider/Default.html).

It's execution time that's slowing you down.  Unfortunately, there's not a whole lot you can do about it.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your talking about the unsightly FOUC (flash of un-styled content).

[Paul Irish](http://paulirish.com/2009/avoiding-the-fouc-v3/) has some tips to avoid this which is more prevalent in ie.

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't see that much of a difference for most interactive uses of JavaScript, which is the kind you find on most websites. However, if you have a lot of loops or do a lot of computation in your script, then you'll see a huge difference between various JS engines. In my experience, Chrome > Firefox > IE in terms of JS engine speed.